# Newsletter subscription mail not sending

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter, registration

I'm having an issue with newsletter email and customer account conformation mail. Whenever someone subscribes to my website or creates an account, my web does not send any mail to the customer.
Is there any enable/disable system in Magento by means of which the mails are not being sent?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: order mails are recieving for admin?

Comment: yeah orders are recieving but customer account conformation and newsletter subscription mails are not being sent to customer's email addresses

Comment: did you checked spam?

Comment: yeah i did @shyam